# Java, Struts2: Getting value from Map in component tag

Tags: java, tags, struts2, action

I have the following case: I am developing a component, which I intend to use by Struta 2 `<s:component>` tag. The tag I am developing is a column header in a List form. The parameter I am passing to the component is the column name. What I want to do and do not exactly know how to do is check if the list is sorted by the particular column. In the action class I have a Map which holds the sortings of the List, but I don't know how to access it dynamically. 
This works:

```
<s:if test="%{sortingKey['id'] == 0}">
  //show ascending sorting for example
</s:if>
```

This does not work:

```
<s:if test="%{sortingKey['%{parameters.fieldName}'] == 0}">
  //show ascending sorting for example
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the parameter is already a string, you should just be able to use:

```
<s:if test="%{sortingKey[parameters.fieldName] == 0}">
```

I'm not sure what the rest of your tag is doing, but I'd use boolean to indicate a true/false value.